# Уникальность в полях двух разных таблиц

Tags: postgresql

Привет!
Как сделать проверку на уникальность данных столбцов двух разных таблиц в базе.
Грубо говоря есть таб1 и колонка кол1, и таб2 и кол2.
Данные должны быть уникальные для обоих колонок. То есть нельзя положить "ххх" в кол1 и кол2.

Comment: Не знаю как posgresql, а все остальные известные мне СУБД такого делать не позволяют. Только триггерами

Comment: Когда возникает такое требование, 80% что структура БД не корректна. Либо эти две таблицы должны быть на самом деле одной, либо должна быть некая объединяющая сущность. А так, да, такое реализуется только триггерами

Answer (score 0):

На несколько таблиц обычное ограничение на уникальность не сделать. Но можно создать третью таблицу (`таб3`) и сделать это в ней:

- `значение`, которое вы проверяете на уникальность — первичный ключ, заодно и уникальность обеспечит
- `ключ1`, внешний ключ на `таб1`, автоматом получаем индекс на него
- `ключ2`, внешний ключ на `таб2`, автоматом получаем индекс на него

И в этой таблице:

- `CHECK`-ограничения: из `ключ1` и `ключ2` **ровно один** `IS NOT NULL`
- `UNIQUE`-ограничение на `ключ1` — чтобы было (1)-к-(0..1), а не (1)-к-(0..N)
- `UNIQUE`-ограничение на `ключ2` по этой же причине

При этом из `таб1` и `таб2` проверяемое на уникальность поле убрать. Совсем. Оно теперь будет храниться в новой таблице.

У этой схемы, впрочем, есть один серьёзный изъян — не получится сделать это поле *обязательным*, т. е. сделать строгий (1)-к-(1), поскольку нет простого (без триггеров) способа потребовать для каждой строчки `таб1` и `таб2` "на неё должна ссылаться хотя бы одна строчка `таб3`" или я о нём не знаю.

---

*На этом, что касается рабочего решения, всё.*

---

Возможно, вы набредёте на интересную функциональность, доступную в постгресе: таблицы с наследованием. И может возникнуть гениальная идея сделать две таблицы с разными ключами на основе одной базовой и наложить ограничение на базовую. Только ничего из этого не получится, потому что [наследование не распространяется на ограничения уникальности, первичные и внешние ключи](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/ddl-inherit.html):

> All check constraints and not-null constraints on a parent table are automatically inherited by its children, unless explicitly specified otherwise with `NO INHERIT` clauses. Other types of constraints **(unique, primary key, and foreign key constraints) are not inherited.**

Так что можете даже не тратить время, пробуя это.